# How to reference Node module dependencies in Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am using the [windows-elevate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-elevate) NPM package which includes an executable as a dependency that launches an elevated command prompt. I would like to call the executable directly from my code.

I can see in the package's code that all it's doing is calling the following:

```js
if (os.arch() === "x64") {
  return path.join(__dirname,'..','dependencies/elevate/bin.x86-64/elevate.exe');
} else {
  return path.join(__dirname,'..','dependencies/elevate/bin.x86-32/elevate.exe');
}
```

So I tried doing something similar in my code, getting a reference to the module from `node_modules` and trying to call the executable from there:

```js
const elevateDirectoryName = path.dirname(require.resolve("windows-elevate/package.json"));

if (os.arch() === "x64") {
  elevatePath = path.join(elevateDirectoryName,'..','dependencies/elevate/bin.x86-64/elevate.exe');
} else {
  elevatePath = path.join(elevateDirectoryName,'..','dependencies/elevate/bin.x86-32/elevate.exe');
}
```

This seems to work in development based on the logs but once I build the executable, I of course get an error that the path isn't correct:

```
Error: ENOENT, node_modules\dependencies\elevate\bin.x86-64\elevate.exe not found in C:\Program Files\ProductName\resources\app.asar
```

How can I properly reference this file in a way that will work in production?

I don't really work on this area of the code so apologies if I missed any details. We are using `electron-builder` to build this app.

Answer (score 0):

Use Electron's `app.getAppPath()` method:

Instead of relying solely on `__dirname`, which may behave differently in development and production, consider using Electron's `app.getAppPath()` method.

```
const { app } = require('electron');
const elevateDirectoryName = path.dirname(require.resolve('windows-elevate/package.json'));

if (os.arch() === 'x64') {
  elevatePath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), elevateDirectoryName, '..', 'dependencies/elevate/bin.x86-64/elevate.exe');
} else {
  elevatePath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), elevateDirectoryName, '..', 'dependencies/elevate/bin.x86-32/elevate.exe');
}
```

If it do not resolve your issue

```
const { app } = require('electron');
const elevateDirectoryName = path.dirname(require.resolve('windows-elevate/package.json'));

let basePath = app.getAppPath();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  basePath = __dirname; 
}

if (os.arch() === 'x64') {
  elevatePath = path.join(basePath, elevateDirectoryName, '..', 'dependencies/elevate/bin.x86-64/elevate.exe');
} else {
  elevatePath = path.join(basePath, elevateDirectoryName, '..', 'dependencies/elevate/bin.x86-32/elevate.exe');
}
```